# Solution for Wordpress URL structure changes and 301 redirects?

Tags: redirect

After a major site review, we've created a new link and category structure to better accommodate URLs and content for the long-term. While we roll out the change, we need to avoid broken links and SEO issues because our category structure is changing.

While best practice is to implement a 301 redirect, is there a solution to automatically redirect all previous categories? Or at least handle it in an efficient way within Wordpress Admin?

**Why this isn't a duplicate:** This is focused on category changes, not just a few changed URLs.

Thanks.

Comment: You can almost certainly accomplish this with an edit to your .htaccess file. If you would care to provide more details (the old category/link structures and the new ones), I/we can help you craft the lines you'd need to add. If there aren't _that many_, and you want to do it from within wordpress, check out http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

Comment: That plugin might be all that's necessary. An admin-integrated solution is best (.htaccess is hard for non-tech) because owners of the site get control, too.

Comment: I believe that when you change category name/permalink, there's a built-in feature in WP that redirects automaticaly to the new name. Easy to test. Not sure if you get a nice 301.

Comment: Cool, glad that helped! I'll post it as an answer so others can see it easily.

Comment: @Simon not as far as I'm aware. I just did this on my site and nothing of the sort happened, thought it might be an issue with my site. Not having more than 1 site I've done this on I can't say definitively.

Comment: @m0r7if3r : I just tried, it works if you change category slug from admin (but not if you change permalink manually into a specific post) since v2.9. But anyway, I guess it would be better adressed with a plugin or htaccess, to keep control.

Comment: @Simon The behaviour I'm seeing with a category change is that it only pulls the previous category tag, it seems finicky but it might as well preserve SEO

Comment: @Simon That's odd...the one I just did was WP3.3.1...that said, part of the reason I had to change it was the bug with custom taxonomy slugs being allowed to overlap with `_builtin` slugs and then getting the two stuck together, so that might be part of the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a large number of redirects, using your .htaccess file is the way to go (assuming you're using apache). If you aren't doing an unreasonable number of redirects and want control within WordPress' Admin, the aptly named [Simple 301 Redirects](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-301-redirects/) is a great option.

Comment: I found simple redirects worked a little better for this particular use case. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Redirection Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/), personally I love it. The log feature is great for keeping an eye on any pages you might have missed and it can do regex redirection through wordpress, or .htaccess...I've heard it works on ngnix as well but have never had the opportunity to test that, so YMMV.

If that's not an option, just go .htaccess and do it by hand, you'll needa regex it or it'll be a MESS (for example, redirect `/old-category/*` to `/new-category/*` rather than `/old-category/page1/` to `/new-category/page1/` and `/old-category/page2/` to `/new-category/page2/`)